# Include more than 2 profiles in Contribution Pages

Tags: profile, contribution-page

I would need to know if it's possible to include more than 2 profiles in a Contribution page, extending the core functionality. 
Does someone of you know whether there is any extension available that adds this feature?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Can you include what CMS you are working with and what version of CiviCRM? It might help you to garner more specific and quality answers.

Comment: I'm using WordPress as CMS and CiviCRM 4.7.25

Answer (score 0):

i do not think this is available. It has come up for discussion several times. CiviEvents offers it and having the same for Contributions would be a good contribution but I gather it is a reasonable effort and no one has taken it on as a community project yet, or fundraised to get it built.

Comment: Thank you. I would need to create a Contribution Page for Membership Sign up with all data of the members needed in my CiviCRM database. They will be a Household and the contacts belonging to this household with their relationships established. I will need this Household and its related contacts to be a member in CiviCRM, establishing their appropriate membership. Could someone guide me what is the best option to develop that functionality? I’ve found some limitations with CiviCRM, as it doesn’t allow to add more than 2 profiles, or to add a set of fields of different contacts in a Profile.

Comment: you will need to explore what the Caldera (?) forms plugin for WP can do I think

Comment: Yes, I'm actually working with Caldera Forms and "CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync" plugin. But, before going further in my development, I would like to make sure if my assumptions are right. I'm trying to create a Form with all data of the contacts needed in my CiviCRM database. They will be WordPress and CiviCRM contacts, with their relationships established in CiviCRM. But, not sure if this plugin allows to create data in the Membership entity, so that those contacts become members.

Comment: You may be better to ask that as a separate question.